# Sitecore Telerik Rich Text Editor - Add a image gallery tool

Tags: telerik, sitecore

Is there a way to add a image gallery wizard in Sitecore RTE for the content authors? The authors should be able to click on the image gallery button in RTE and select the required images to create a gallery. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The RTE allows to add controls, an example can be found [here](https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2016/09/23/add-custom-list-button-in-sitecore-rte/)